# how to make all lines black in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, color

```
\documentclass{article} % lualatex
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        samples=40,
        domain=-3:3,
        axis equal=true,
        ]
        \addplot3 [contour lua={levels={1,1.5,2},labels=false}] {x^2+y^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to make the three circles all black (now, they are red, yellow, blue), but `\addplot3 [black, contour lua={levels={1,1.5,2},labels=false}] {x^2+y^2};` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} % lualatex
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        samples=40,
        domain=-3:3,
        axis equal=true,
        ]
        \addplot3 [contour lua={levels={1,1.5,2},labels=false,draw color=black}] {x^2+y^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `draw color` is on page 160 of `texdoc pgfplots`, sorry I did not find it.